# php lucene how to update and delete rows in index file

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene

There is time when users change the content of their post, content field in actual database will get updated.

how can I get the same field the index file updated as well?

And when users delete a post how can I delete that post in the index file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used lucene search with Symfony and here is how I use it:

```
// Called when an object is saved
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {
    $conn = $conn ? $conn : $this->getTable()->getConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $ret = parent::save($conn);

        $this->updateLuceneIndex();

        $conn->commit();

        return $ret;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
}

public function updateLuceneIndex() {
    $index = $this->getTable()->getLuceneIndex();

    // remove existing entries
    foreach ($index->find('pk:' . $this->getId()) as $hit) {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
    }

    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

    // store job primary key to identify it in the search results
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('pk', $this->getId()));

    // index job fields
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unStored('title', Utils::stripAccent($this->getTitle()), 'utf-8'));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unStored('summary', Utils::stripAccent($this->getSummary()), 'utf-8'));

    // add job to the index
    $index->addDocument($doc);
    $index->commit();
}

// Called when an object is deleted
public function delete(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {
    $index = $this->getTable()->getLuceneIndex();

    foreach ($index->find('pk:' . $this->getId()) as $hit) {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
    }

    return parent::delete($conn);
}
```

And here is how I get my index:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('Work');
}

static public function getLuceneIndexFile() {
    return sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir') . '/indexes/work.' . sfConfig::get('sf_environment') . '.index';
}

static public function getLuceneIndex() {
    ProjectConfiguration::registerZend();

    if (file_exists($index = self::getLuceneIndexFile())) {

        return Zend_Search_Lucene::open($index);
    } else {
        return Zend_Search_Lucene::create($index);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: I have a small query on this code. How can you use find() in an unindexed field?