# Zend Lucene Delete Document Issue

Tags: zend-lucene

I am trying to delete a document using zend lucene. The following is my code

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('data/index');
foreach ($index->find('pk:' . $this->getId()) as $hit) {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
    }
$index->commit();
```

When I run this and checked my index folder there is a new file created like this
_f4t5_1.del

But when I do a search, the deleted document is available in the search and also checked the

$index->numDocs();

This method also returns the same count before and after delete.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the issue. The issue was due to a logical error in my code. After deleting I was calling another function which again added the document to the index. When I checked the document ID if found it to be different after deleting and that helped me to track the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful: [php lucene how to update and delete rows in index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143180/php-lucene-how-to-update-and-delete-rows-in-index-file)

Have you checked to make sure the documents are actually deleted.

> **Zend_Search_Lucene::isDeleted($id)** method may be used to check if a
>   document is deleted.
>
> ```
> for ($count = 0; $count < $index->maxDoc(); $count++) {
>     if ($index->isDeleted($count)) {
>         echo "Document #$id is deleted.\n";
>     }
> }
> ```

Have you tried running [index optimization](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.optimization):

> Index optimization removes deleted documents and squeezes documents'
>   IDs in to a smaller range. A document's internal id may therefore
>   change during index optimization.

Comment: I tried optimizing the index. When optimized it removed the files like with extension .del but when searched the index, the deleted documents are also returned in the search results.

Comment: Why not loop through and use `$index->isDeleted($id)` to remove the deleted documents from the search results.